# Is there any significance to the pathways and roads in Don't Starve?

Tags: dont-starve

Is there any purpose to the roads and pathways in Don't Starve?  I know that you can run faster when you are on them.  But, do they tend to lead to anything in particular, or is there any other significance to them?

So far I've not found that they lead anywhere, but I was wondering if there is a greater significance in the game a later time, etc.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, roads are often connected to eachother. Most pig villages have a road coming in, sinkholes to caves are always near roads. Add this to the speed of exploring,  and it becomes clear why following roads is very interesting.

You can craft your own roads, too. For faster acces between your favorite parts of the map.

Answer (score 0):

Plants like Berry Bushes, Grass Tufts, Saplings, Spiky Bushes, Pine Cones, and Birchnuts can't be planted on [Cobblestones](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Cobblestones), unless they were planted before these turfs were placed.

But it is more effortless just to use [Rocky Turf](http://dontstarve.wikia.com/wiki/Rocky_Turf) for this purpose.